# How to use the unallocated space above /boot to expand my root directory

Tags: partitioning, gparted, root, storage

[image: screenshot]

here's the screenshot of my gparted screen. I am a newbie at Ubuntu and I dont think that deleting /boot and recreating it would be a wise idea since deleting it also formats it(i think). Please help as soon as possible my root is at 100% usage.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. If it were me; I'd boot a live disk (eg. Ubuntu install media), create a new '/' partition (say 30gb, min. 15gb which may still have issues upgrading to next release so 24gb+), then `cp` (copy) your files across to this partition. You can then `diff` (compare & show differences; should be none!) to ensure data across safe, then edit UUIDs so correct for new partition and have it boot instead...  (deleting & re-using the small old partition can be done later)

Comment: What do you have using up so much space? Try `sudo apt autoremove` to clean up /.

Comment: @ravery tried it. cleaned only 86 MB :/

Comment: moving boot files can cause a boot errors. So, it is best to do as guiverc suggests.

Comment: @guiverc any way to do it without the live USB? I actually dont have a bootable ubuntu USB as of now.

Comment: you can do most now; but files are currently open & in use, so `cp` will not get ideal results so you'll have to create a `chroot` partition just so you can unmount / for cp..., then you'll have another partition to later delete. this is a LOT of extra work.   maybe 30mins extra versus a USB thumb-drive; I'd choose the 'live' ...

Answer (score 1):

The basic approach would be the following -

1. Boot using a LiveCD
2. Move your boot partition. Increase the size of root partition by merging with the unallocated space. Use `gparted`.
3. Update your fstab file at `/etc/fstab`. Use the `blkid` command to know the UUID's of the new partitions.
4. run `grub-install` for the new boot location (use the `--boot-directory=` option).

Hope that helps.